# merge chromosomes in Plink

Tags: merge, genetics

I have downloaded 1000G dataset in the vcf format. Using Plink 2.0 I have converted them into binary format.
Now I need to merge the 1-22 chromosomes.
I am using this script:

```
${BIN}plink2 \
--bfile /mnt/jw01-aruk-home01/projects/jia_mtx_gwas_2016/common_files/data/clean/thousand_genomes/from_1000G_web/chr1_1000Gv3 \
--make-bed \
--merge-list /mnt/jw01-aruk-home01/projects/jia_mtx_gwas_2016/common_files/data/clean/thousand_genomes/from_1000G_web/chromosomes_1000Gv3.txt \
--out /mnt/jw01-aruk-home01/projects/jia_mtx_gwas_2016/common_files/data/clean/thousand_genomes/from_1000G_web/all_chrs_1000G_v3 \
--noweb
```

But, I get this error

> Error: --merge-list only accepts 1 parameter.

The chromosomes_1000Gv3.txt has files related to chromosomes 2-22 in this format:

chr2_1000Gv3.bed chr2_1000Gv3.bim chr2_1000Gv3.fam

chr3_1000Gv3.bed chr3_1000Gv3.bim chr3_1000Gv3.fam

....

Any suggestions what might be the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The --merge-list cannot be used in combination with --bfile. You can either have --bfile/--bmerge or --merge-list only in one plink command.